# Retrieving available titles in full outer join of 4 tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to consolidate the output of 4 different attribute tables. All tables have different row count. Currently I have this query:

```
    CREATE VIEW vw_Items

AS
SELECT   a.Countryname
        ,a.Itemname
        ,ISNULL(a.Colour,'None') as Colour
        ,ISNULL(b.Location,0) as Location
        ,ISNULL(c.Size,0) as Size
        ,ISNULL(d.Weight,0) as Weight

FROM ItemColour a

FULL OUTER JOIN ItemLocation b 
    ON a.Countryname = b.Countryname 
    AND a.Itemname= b.Itemname
FULL OUTER JOIN ItemSize c 
    ON a.Countryname = c.Countryname 
    AND a.Itemname= c.Itemname
FULL OUTER JOIN ItemWeight d 
    ON a.Countryname = d.Countryname 
    AND a.Itemname= d.Itemname
```

So, the issue is with NULL countryname and Itemname in table a, for which I think I need to do a nested CASE, but is there a better way to handle this?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Explain what you want in the results set. `FULL JOIN` is almost never needed and it is not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might want:

```
SELECT ci.Countryname, ci.Itemname
       COALESCE(c.Colour, 'None') as Colour,
       COALESCE(l.Location, 0) as Location
       COALESCE(s.Size, 0) as Size
       COALESCE(w.Weight, 0) as Weight
FROM ((SELECT c.countryname, c.itemname
       FROM ItemColour c
      ) UNION  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (SELECT l.countryname, l.itemname
       FROM ItemLocation c
      ) UNION
      (SELECT s.countryname, s.itemname
       FROM ItemSize
      ) UNION
      (SELECT w.countryname, w.itemname
       FROM ItemWeight w
      ) 
     ) ci LEFT JOIN
     ItemColor c
     ON c.countryname = ci.countryname AND
        c.itemname = ci.itemname LEFT JOIN
     ItemLocation l
     ON l.countryname = ci.countryname AND
        l.itemname = ci.itemname LEFT JOIN
     ItemSize s
     ON s.countryname = ci.countryname AND
        s.itemname = ci.itemname LEFT JOIN
     ItemWeight w
     ON w.countryname = ci.countryname AND
        w.itemname = ci.itemname ;
```

Comment: Interesting. Will check and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that works better than mine, I might have 2 rows for the same country/item combo whilst yours eliminates this issue and works a bit faster. 6 seconds vs 7 seconds.